# Question about a proof in uniqueness of limit in Abbott's "Understanding Analysis"

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

In Abbott's textbook "Understanding Analysis", first edition, exercise 2.3.4 (page 49), it is asked: "Show that limits, if they exist, must be unique. In other words, assume $\lim a_n=l_1$ and $\lim a_n=l_2$ and prove that $l_1=l_2$."

In its solutions manual, the proof is the following: "Let $\epsilon>0$, we know that $\lim a_n=l_1$ so there exists $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \ge N_1 \implies |a_n-l_1|<\epsilon/2$. Similarly, since $\lim a_n=l_2$ there exists $N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \ge N_2 \implies |a_n-l_2|<\epsilon/2$. Setting $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$, gives us that for $n \ge N$ it is $|l_1-l_2|\le|a_n-l_1|+|a_n-l_2|<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon$, thus $|l_1-l_2|<\epsilon$. From the fact that two real numbers $a$ and $b$ are equal if and only if for every real number $\epsilon>0$ it follows that $|a-b|<\epsilon$, it is $l_1=l_2$."

My question is the following: the indexes $N_1$ and $N_2$ are actually $N_1=N_1(\epsilon)$ and $N_2=N_2(\epsilon)$, and so it is $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$, that is $N=N(\epsilon)$. I always seen the
aforementioned result on $a$ and $b$ as something like "when $\epsilon$ become smaller and smaller, the distance between $a$ and $b$ becomes arbitrarily small and so they must coincide"; however, in this case, the estimations on the distance $|l_1-l_2|$ hold only when $n \ge \max\{N_1,N_2\}$, the latter depending on $\epsilon$; so how can Abbott be sure that, as $\epsilon$ varies to become smaller and smaller (and so does $N$) the condition $n \ge \max\{N_1,N_2\}$ is still verified since $\max\{N_1,N_2\}$ varies with $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Abbott proves is that, for *each* $\varepsilon>0$, $|l_1-l_2|<\varepsilon$. In order to do this, he picks $N_1,N_2\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N_1\implies|a_n-l_1|<\frac\varepsilon2$ and that $n\geqslant N_2\implies|b_n-l_2|<\frac\varepsilon2$. And, yes, the numbers $N_1$ and $N_2$ depend upon $\varepsilon$. Then, if $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$,$$n\geqslant N\implies|a_n-l_|,|b_n-l_2|<\frac\varepsilon2\implies|l_1-l_2|<\varepsilon.$$Again, yes, $N$ depends upon $\varepsilon$. But that's irrelevant. What matters is that Abbott has proved that, for *each* $\varepsilon>0$, $|l_1-l_2|<\varepsilon$. At this point of the proof, $N_1$, $N_2$, and $N$ are gone. And now, since $|l_1-l_2|\geqslant0$ and since there is nor real number greater than $0$ which is smaller than any other real number greater than $0$, we must have $|l_1-l_2|=0$.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still confused. This question arised after reading the OP solution here
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4423777/solution-verification-of-f-periodic-and-lim-x-to-infty-fx-exists-imp
OP's argument and Abbott's one seems the same to me, but OP's one is consided wrong. Maybe they differ because here $l_1$ and $l_2$ are fixed real numbers while in the linked question $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ depends on $\epsilon$ from the inequalities $x_1,x_2 \ge M_\epsilon$, so they don't obey to $\forall \epsilon |a-b|<\epsilon \implies a=b$ because $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ are not fixed?

Comment: I would love to answer to that, but you've done it your self. In the proof from my answer, when I reach $|l_1-l_2|<\varepsilon$, the number $N$ is not mentioned anymore. But in that other question, you cannot jump from $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\varepsilon$ to $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|=0$ because $x_1$ and $x_2$ are *not* fixed numbers. They were chosen depending on $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the confirmation! Yes I always prefer to try to give an answer myself and ask to confirmation to experts, because I find it more didactic and less time expensive for the one who's helping me.